# ReactNative ReactNavigation tab bar customization problems

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a problem. I researhed but I could not find anything.

I am trying to write an application in React Native. I am thinking of a bar with five bars in tab bar. The button in the middle is a little bit higher than the others. I do not know how to do this with reactnavigator. Let me Show you some attempts:
Firstly my navigatör structure is like this:

```
    <NavigationContainer >
                <Tab.Navigator
                    screenOptions={{
                        headerShown: false,
                        tabBarStyle: {
                            backgroundColor: 'rgba(166,65,28,1)',
                            borderTopLeftRadius: 40,
                            borderTopRightRadius: 40,
                            height: 50

                        },
                        tabBarLabelStyle: {
                            color: '#fff',
                            fontFamily: 'Arial-Narrow'

                        }
                    }}

                >
                    <Tab.Screen name="İlan Ara"
                        component={TestView4}
                        options={{
                            headerShown: false,
                            tabBarHideOnKeyboard: true,
                            tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
                                <Image source={require('./assets/tab-bar-icons/search.png')} style={{ width: 19, height: 19 }} />

                            ),
                            style: {
                                backgroundColor: 'red'
                            }
                        }}
                    >
                    </Tab.Screen>
                    <Tab.Screen name="İlan Ver"
                        component={TestView4}
                        options={{
                            headerShown: false,
                            tabBarHideOnKeyboard: true,
                            tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
                                <Image source={require('./assets/tab-bar-icons/plus.png')} style={{ width: 19, height: 19 }} />

                            )
                        }}
                    >
                    </Tab.Screen>
                    <Tab.Screen name="İlanlarım"
                        component={TestView4}
                        options={{
                            headerShown: false,
                            tabBarHideOnKeyboard: true,
                            tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
                                <View>
                                    <Image source={require('./assets/tab-bar-icons/logo-bg.png')}
                                        style={{
                                            width: 40,
                                            height: 40
                                        }}
                                    />
                                </View>

                            ),
                            tabBarStyle: {
                                backgroundColor: 'blue',
                                borderTopLeftRadius: 40,
                                borderTopRightRadius: 40,
                                paddingTop: 10
                            },
                        }}
                    >
                    </Tab.Screen>
                    <Tab.Screen name="Mesajlar"
                        component={TestView4}
                        options={{
                            headerShown: false,
                            tabBarHideOnKeyboard: true,
                            tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
                                <Image source={require('./assets/tab-bar-icons/send.png')} style={{ width: 19, height: 19 }} />

                            )
                        }}
                    >
                    </Tab.Screen>
                    <Tab.Screen
                        name="Profil"
                        options={{
                            headerShown: false,
                            tabBarHideOnKeyboard: true,
                            tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
                                <Image source={require('./assets/tab-bar-icons/profile.png')} style={{ width: 19, height: 19 }} />

                            ),
                            style: {
                                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,1)'
                            }
                        }}

                    >
                        {() => (
                            <ProfileStack.Navigator>
                                <ProfileStack.Screen
                                    name="AuthIndex"
                                    component={AuthIndex}
                                    options={{
                                        headerShown: false,
                                        tabBarHideOnKeyboard: true
                                    }}
                                    screenOptions={{ animationEnabled: false, headerShown: false }}
                                />
                                <ProfileStack.Screen
                                    name="Profile"
                                    component={Profile}
                                    options={{
                                        headerShown: false,
                                        tabBarHideOnKeyboard: true
                                    }}

                                />
                                <ProfileStack.Screen
                                    name="Login"
                                    component={Login}
                                    options={{
                                        headerShown: false,
                                        tabBarHideOnKeyboard: true
                                    }}

                                />
                                <ProfileStack.Screen
                                    name="Register"
                                    component={Register}
                                    options={{
                                        headerShown: false,
                                        tabBarHideOnKeyboard: true
                                    }}

                                />
                                <ProfileStack.Screen
                                    name="ForgotPassword"
                                    component={ForgotPassword}
                                    options={{
                                        headerShown: false,
                                        tabBarHideOnKeyboard: true
                                    }}

                                />
                                <ProfileStack.Screen
                                    name="ProfileEdit"
                                    component={ProfileEdit}
                                    options={{
                                        headerShown: false,
                                        tabBarHideOnKeyboard: true
                                    }}


                                />

                                <ProfileStack.Screen
                                    name="Cars"
                                    component={Cars}
                                    options={{
                                        title: 'Araçlarım',
                                        headerStyle: {
                                            backgroundColor: '#FFF',
                                        },
                                        headerTintColor: '#5e5e5e',
                                    }}

                                />
                            </ProfileStack.Navigator>
                        )}
                    </Tab.Screen>

                </Tab.Navigator>

            </NavigationContainer >
```

There is the “moy posts” menü in the middle of the five-menu navigatör.I gave view to it in order to have the menü aliitle higher and ı changed the position value as absolute and gave the top value nagative. So that it stayed higher than the others.
[this my tab bar please click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkiXg.png)

This editing made the menü to positiıon higher than the others. However the problem is this: this higher menü comes over the design and becaues the tab bar doesn’t come down at all, the buton comes over the upper “kaydet” button.

[this image please click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKsBf.png)

If I try tor ise the margin Top value of the middle menü,
this happens.
[this image please click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzAKv.png)

Even I do marginBottom nothing changes What I want is, a way to keep the middle menü from overlapping with the “kaydet” button above.

Answer (score 0):

You should apply a Floating Button with a z-index = 1 or something in the styling.